# separate (dplyr) with key in-between specific characters (after space and before capital letter)

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I want to dplyr::separate on a minus (-) that has to be after a space and before a capital letter.

My regex `[\s]-[A-Z]` includes the space and capital letter, hence removes by separating. I only want to use the minus at that specific location for separation, not getting rid of the space and following letter.

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = c("Hans-Peter Wurst -My Gosh", "What is -wrong here -Do not worry")) %>% 
  separate(x, into = c("one", "two"), sep = "[\\s]-[A-Z]")
```

Results in:

```
#                   one         two
# 1    Hans-Peter Wurst      y Gosh
# 2 What is -wrong here o not worry
```

Desired output would be:

```
#                   one          two
# 1    Hans-Peter Wurst      My Gosh
# 2 What is -wrong here Do not worry
```

Comment: Ok, I reopened it as I am getting headache with these talks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wrap the uppercase letter pattern within a lookbehind/lookahead

```
sep = "(?<!\\S)-(?=[A-Z])"
```

Or, if the `-` at the start of the string must be excluded use

```
sep = "(?<=\\s)-(?=[A-Z])"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w7wJfx/1)

Since [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are zero-width assertions that do not consume text (the text they match does not land inside the overall match value, it only checks if the pattern matches and returns true or false) the letter will be kept in the output.

**Details**

- `(?<=\s)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind that requires start of a string position or a whitespace immediately to the left of the current location
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=[A-Z])` - a positive lookahead that requires an uppercase ASCII letter immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: If OP's text is to be believed, *"not getting rid of the space and following letter"*, might need to also use a look-behind for the space.

Comment: @Gregor Fair enough, I replaced the `\s+` with `(?<!\S)` that matches a position at the start of the string or after a whitespace. `(?<=\s)` might be better if the start position must be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `extract` where we capture the characters as a group (`(..)`).  by leave those characters not needed out of the brackets

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = c("Hans-Peter Wurst -My Gosh", 
               "What is -wrong here -Do not worry")) %>%
     extract(x, into = c("one", "two"), "(.*) -([^-]+)$")
#                 one          two
#1    Hans-Peter Wurst      My Gosh
#2 What is -wrong here Do not worry
```